# Website is not centering on mobile

Tags: html, css

im creating simple website. On desktop, whole content is centered ok. It works also with changing size of browser. 
But when I visited it on mobile, everything is not centered like on desktop

Take a look: http://piaskownica.lokalnamanufaktura.pl/metod2/

I think that my css wrap class for centering is buggy. Videobackground also is not centered on desktop.

```
.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
}
```

Comment: try changing the size of the text '403' from pixels to percentage.. if its in pixels..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.x2-horizontal` has a width of `380px` that is too wide for small screens. Watch out for fixed widths in responsive designs.

Your layout method is not ideal. For a start, think of devices that don't support `transform`.

The video control won't center using `margin: auto` because of `position: absolute`. You'd have to use the same kind of centering methos as for the other content (i.e. `left: 50%` and then pulling it back 50% of its width.)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the wrap is getting crushed too small to contain all of the elements. Perhaps you could use a media query to reduce their size on mobile. A simple solution for this case would be

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        zoom: .8;
    }
}
```

which would reduce the size of the whole body to 80% so that it doesn't overflow and wrap to new lines. In addition, if you want to center your background video, try changing the `bottom` and `right` to `50%` instead of `0` in the `#video_background`, and also add your transform lines onto that.

```
#video_background {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -1000;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(50%) translateY(50%);
}
```